# How to deal with nested rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't seem to wrap my head around the following, I have a simple spaceship with 2  turrets:

[image]

My 'Player' the white ship has a rigidbody. The turrets have not.

[image][image]

I'm moving and rotating my player via the rigidBody, however I would like to also rotate the turrets via the physics system.

I thought about adding a rigidBody2D to the turrets, however that was not recommended from my understanding reading posts online. This is because rigidbodies in children would affect the parent in unforseen ways.

So dropping that idea, **How can I move my turret and having it be affected by physics?**

Some sidenotes:
I want the turrets to be influenced by physics. Lets say i try to rotate my turret, but it hits a wall, I want it to resist. Lets say some debris hit my turret's barrel, I want it to move in the opposite direction.

Although i could move the turret outside of its parent's container (the ship) I do ofcourse want it to 'stay on the ship in game'. The turret is part of the ship, its mounted to the hull or fuselage if you will. So it should move with the ship and keep its position.

Comment: `How to deal with nested rigidbody?`  -> **Don't!** If you need to combine Rigidbodies you should rather use [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Joints.html) .. in your specific case probably [`HingeJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html)

Comment: @derHugo hello, thanks for taking the time to answer me. Could you explain a bit more, what would my hierarchy look like (ship, turrets etc) when using this approach? And am i correct to assume that I should add the joint (and a rb) to the turret, and connect it to the ship's rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by derHugo joints where up for the task, although i had to restructure a bit, here is the outcome:

I added an empty transform to hold the ship and its sub-components, so turrets are no longer part of the ship parent, so that i can add a rigidBody to these child objects now.

Then I added a hingejoint and rigidbody to the player ét voila, it now works:

[image]

I still need to take a good look at how joints work exactly but this seems to work.